# Asus X551ca HDMI resolution

Tags: hdmi

I have an X551CA laptop and an ASUS 2K monitor.  I can connect the laptop and monitor, all works well, but my max resolution seems to be 1920x1080.

Any suggestions/advice on how to get the full 2K?

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1200, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected 1366x768+0+432 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768      59.99*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1200+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1200     59.95* 
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    59.93  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

The CPU is an i3-3217 @ 1.8ghz, the monitor is a VX24A

Comment: Can you please add the output of `xrandr`, run in a terminal, to your question. That might give more information.

Comment: @Thomas - added

Comment: Your external display is running at 1920x1200, which might be a limit. I don't know the CPU model and monitor model. You might want to add that as well to your question. [Here](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/articles/000025675/graphics-drivers.html) is also an overview of the supported resolutions of the Intel Graphics.

Comment: @Thomas - post updated (CPU/i3, Monitor/VX24A)

Comment: It looks like the Intel Graphics 4000 of the CPU does only support 1920x1200 over HDMI. With Display Port a higher resolution should be possible. According to [this post](https://www.notebookcheck.net/2560x1440-or-2560x1600-via-HDMI.92840.0.html), it also should be possible over HDMI, but I wouldn't suggest that.

Comment: @Thomas - thanks. I tried a method similar to your link and it wonked my laptop display (and didn't display 2K anyway).  

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum resolution of the Intel HD Graphics 4000 of the i3-3217 CPU is 1920x1200 over HDMI, due to single link HDMI.

[In this post](https://www.notebookcheck.net/2560x1440-or-2560x1600-via-HDMI.92840.0.html) there is a method that may work to increase to resolution.
Another option would be to use DisplayPort if possible, as DisplayPort should support a higher resolution out of the box.